# Ubuntu 16.04 bootload grub2 problem?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, partitioning, mbr

Ok, I have an internal SSD installed with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Upon installation I deleted both partitions on both disks and installed Ubuntu on the SSD. I have a Lenovo V570 with the CD Drive replaced with a HDD 2.5 adapter holding a 1TB Hitachi. SSD installed in original HDD factory slot. I keep getting the issue of black screen and high fan usage when booting with the HDD connected. Even after Deleting and recreating both partitions on both disks, I still get this issue. The HDD did previously have Windows 7 installed on it. It has since had a new partition made on the device. I have looked everywhere for a solution. I have been unable to find out why this is happening. Can you give me some diagnostic commands to be able to find out what is happening?

P.S. Windows is not installed anymore. I have the most updated bios for that model: V43

Comment: Black screen after Bios, before grub load screen

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous comment, so I assume there is no issue with the BIOS. Once you get Grub2 menu, can you press "e" that can be used to temporarily change the boot options, and remove "quiet" and "slash" options?

Comment: The Grub menu doesn't load. All I get is black screen.

Comment: okay, you just answered a bit before I update my post. I assume that you didn't have any problem with the 1TB HDD disconnected?

Comment: Nope, no problem loading when 1TB HDD disconnected. Not sure if relevant, 1TB HDD is ext4 formatted, no boot flag.

Comment: This is likely due to BIOS settings like the boot order which is unrelated to Ubuntu and therefore off topic here. You can ask about BIOS issues over on [SU].

Answer (score 0):

You computer may try to start on the second hard drive (1TB). First, try to update in your BIOS settings if you can move ahead your SSD in the boot order. If not possible, you may have to delete the boot sector on the 1TB hard drive in order to denied the BIOS to boot on it. To archive this, boot on Live USB and use the following command:

```
# Identify your 1TB hard drive)
sudo fdisk -l
# Remove the boot sector (fill up by zero), replace sdx by the 1TB hard drive
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=446 count=1
```

[Source](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/erase-your-mbr/)

Comment: I ran this command using /dev/sdb. I reset defaults on my bios. I noticed a change in  boot menu where there was windows boot loader added. I noticed SDD serial was listed as ATA HDD in boot options. In under 'Boot' option. I moved SSD to top, and HDD directly under. Restarted saving changes. Still black screen after boot with 1TB HDD connected.

Comment: I do know that bios version 43 is UEFI compatible, but does not have secure boot option in bios settings.

Comment: Relevance questionable: I did install Ubuntu with Yumi/Multiboot USB made on windows with a windows 7 x64 image also installed. This shouldn't have installed a windows boot loader alongside grub. There is no option in Grub for Windows boot loader either.

Comment: Bios boot list:
USB HDD,
USB FDD,
Ubuntu,
Windows Boot Loader,
ATA HDD: SDD,
ATA HDD: HDD Hitachi

I still get black screen

Comment: [Grub2BootOptions](https://photos.app.goo.gl/psga4ojS11oEncy82) This is the image of my grub2 boot screen for Ubuntu 16.04. Windows boot loader does not show in main menu.

Comment: [boot repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25622109/) This is the report from boot-info. found at this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)

Comment: I ran Boot-repair, and got this [readout](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25622183/). Will reboot momentarily hoping this will work to fix the problem.

Comment: The problem still persists.... :(

Comment: I afraid that you BIOS prevents correct booting when you have this secondary HD.

Comment: Weird, I put a USB flash in the USB port, and it loaded correctly. I would like to know how I can get a log from the bios if there is a way.